# Getting "muleContext cannot be resolved" error in mule Junit test code

Tags: java, junit, mule, junit4, junit3

I am getting error "Unresolved compilation problem: 
    muleContext cannot be resolved" at the line "MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();" in JUnit test code in Mule. As per my understanding this code is correct. Since i am new to JUnit, i am not getting why this error is coming. Can anyone help me to getout from this problem please.

For your information below are the flow and Junit test code.

**Junit Test:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.mule.api.client.MuleClient;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mule.api.MuleContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.util.IOUtils;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class sampleTest extends TestCase {

    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "src/main/app/file-transfer-test.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testFile() throws Exception {
        MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
        String fileInputPath = "src/test/resources/InputFiles/Contacts1.csv";
        String payload = IOUtils.getResourceAsString("src/main/app/file-transfer-test.xml", this.getClass());
        client.dispatch(fileInputPath, payload, null);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        MuleMessage result = client.request("src/test/resources/OutputFiles", 10000);
        System.out.println("The result is \n" +result +"\n The payload is : \n" +payload);
    }
}
```

**Mule flow:**

```
<flow name="file-transfer-testFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path\Lineage="D:\AnyPointStudio\1SampleFTPFiles\InputFiles" moveToPattern="Contacts1.csv" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <logger message="File content :: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\AnyPointStudio\1SampleFTPFiles\OtuputFiles" outputPattern="outputfile.csv" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an active `MuleContext` during your test, you need to extend `FunctionalTestCase`:

```
import org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase;

public class SampleTest extends FunctionalTestCase {
```

Comment: Hi David, I have done as you said, but still getting same error. Is there anyother solution to solve this..?

Comment: Hi, The error "Unresolved compilation problem: muleContext cannot be resolved" has resolved and now i am getting new error i.e, "org.mule.api.registry.ServiceException: Failed to load transport: org/mule/transport D". Help me to solve this as well.

Comment: You're probably missing the file transport JAR in your build path.

Comment: Please accept my answer because it correctly resolves the issue for this question.

Comment: Yes Devid, the problem has resolved after adding required jars. Thank you for your suggesion.