# Getting Exception "Failed to load transport: org/mule/transport D"

Tags: java, junit, mule, junit4, junit3

I am getting below exception in Junit test code in Mule. You can find my mule flow and test code here :[Getting "muleContext cannot be resolved" error in mule Junit test code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439724/getting-mulecontext-cannot-be-resolved-error-in-mule-junit-test-code)

Can anyone help me to resove this error please.

```
org.mule.api.registry.ServiceException: Failed to load transport: org/mule/transport D
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.createServiceDescriptor(MuleRegistryHelper.java:563)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupServiceDescriptor(MuleRegistryHelper.java:537)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultEndpointFactory.getEndpointBuilder(DefaultEndpointFactory.java:125)
    at org.mule.endpoint.SimpleEndpointCache.getOutboundEndpoint(SimpleEndpointCache.java:45)
    at org.mule.client.DefaultLocalMuleClient.send(DefaultLocalMuleClient.java:113)
    at org.mule.client.DefaultLocalMuleClient.send(DefaultLocalMuleClient.java:101)
    at fileTestCase.sampleTest.testFile(sampleTest.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$StatementThread.run(FailOnTimeout.java:74)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing the file transport JAR in your build path.

Comment: Yes Devid, the problem has resolved after adding required jars. Thank you for your suggesion.

Comment: `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>`